# Why do I get the error DTD is not allowed on this document?

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

Heres the code:

// iBEC/iBSS -> SHSH Generator Tool

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SHSH_Tool
{
    public enum VersionMode
    {
        V3_0 = 0,
        V3_0_1
    }

```
class Program
{
    static void PrintUsage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("iBEC/iBSS to SHSH Tool");
        Console.WriteLine("Usage: SHSH_Tool -tmpfiles X:\\Path\\To\\Tmp\\Directories -output X:\\Path\\To\\00.SHSH");
        Console.WriteLine("Note: If you have files for 3.0.1, use the -301 switch.");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VersionMode toolMode = VersionMode.V3_0;

        string firmwareRootPath = null; // @"E:\Work\Dev\iPhone\iBEC_iBSS_Grabber";
        string outputFilename = null; // @"E:\Work\Dev\svn\iPhone\SHSH_Tool\3.0.shsh";

        string lastArg = null;
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            if (arg == "-301")
            {
                toolMode = VersionMode.V3_0_1;
            }

            if (lastArg == "-tmpfiles")
            {
                firmwareRootPath = arg;
            }
            else if (lastArg == "-output")
            {
                outputFilename = arg;
            }

            lastArg = arg.ToLower();
        }

        if (firmwareRootPath == null || outputFilename == null)
        {
            PrintUsage();

            return;
        }
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(firmwareRootPath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to open TMP directories path.");

            PrintUsage();

            return;
        }

        string restoreRamDiskToIgnore = "018-5304-002.dmg";
        string manifestFilename = "BuildManifest.30.xml";
        string shshTemplateFilename = "3.0.shsh.template";
        if (toolMode == VersionMode.V3_0_1)
        {
            restoreRamDiskToIgnore = "018-5804-001.dmg";
            manifestFilename = "BuildManifest.30.xml";
            shshTemplateFilename = "3.0.1.shsh.template";

            Console.WriteLine("Operating in 3.0.1 Mode");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operating in 3.0 Mode");
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading IPSW Manifest File...");
            //System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Util.ReadEmbeddedResource(manifestFilename));
            BuildManifestReader manifestReader = new BuildManifestReader(manifestFilename);

            Console.WriteLine("Found Manifest Files:");
            foreach (BuildManifestItem manifestItem in manifestReader.ManifestItems.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - Key: " + manifestItem.Key + " [Digest: " + manifestItem.PartialDigest + "]");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Processing TMP files...");
            string strECID = null;
            string[] subdirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(firmwareRootPath);
            foreach (string subdir in subdirs)
            {
                if (!(subdir.Contains("Per") && subdir.EndsWith(".tmp")))
                    continue;

                Console.WriteLine(" - Entering directory: " + subdir);
                ProcessSubdirectory(subdir, manifestReader, ref strECID);
            }

            // Process current directory
            ProcessSubdirectory(firmwareRootPath, manifestReader, ref strECID);

            bool blobsOK = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Verifying BLOB Data...");
            foreach (BuildManifestItem manifestItem in manifestReader.ManifestItems.Values)
            {
                if (manifestItem.BlobData == null && manifestItem.Path != restoreRamDiskToIgnore)
                {
                    if (manifestItem.Found)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" - ERROR: Invalid signed data for " + manifestItem.Path);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" - ERROR: File not found for " + manifestItem.Path);
                    }
                    blobsOK = false;
                }
            }

            if (blobsOK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating custom SHSH file...");
                System.IO.StreamReader shshTemplateFileHdl = new System.IO.StreamReader(Util.ReadEmbeddedResource(shshTemplateFilename));
                string shshTemplateFile = shshTemplateFileHdl.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (BuildManifestItem manifestItem in manifestReader.ManifestItems.Values)
                {
                    shshTemplateFile = shshTemplateFile.Replace("[BLOB-" + manifestItem.Path + "]", manifestItem.BlobData);
                    shshTemplateFile = shshTemplateFile.Replace("[DIGEST-" + manifestItem.Path + "]", manifestItem.PartialDigest);
                }

                System.IO.StreamWriter shshFileWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFilename);
                shshFileWriter.Write(shshTemplateFile);
                shshFileWriter.Close();

                if (toolMode == VersionMode.V3_0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success!  3.0 SHSH File stored at " + outputFilename);
                }
                else if (toolMode == VersionMode.V3_0_1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success!  3.0.1 SHSH File stored at " + outputFilename);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There were errors while trying to create SHSH file.");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There were errors while trying to create SHSH file.");
            Console.WriteLine("Diagnostic: " + e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Complete.");
        }
    }

    static bool ProcessSubdirectory(string subdir, BuildManifestReader manifestReader, ref string strECID)
    {
        foreach (BuildManifestItem manifestItem in manifestReader.ManifestItems.Values)
        {
            if (manifestItem.BlobData != null)
                continue;

            string path = manifestItem.Path.Replace("/", "\\");
            string searchPath = subdir + "\\" + path;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(searchPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  - " + manifestItem.Path);

                if (!ProcessFile(searchPath, manifestItem, ref strECID))
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                string fileOnly = manifestItem.Path.Substring(manifestItem.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                searchPath = subdir + "\\" + fileOnly;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(searchPath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  - [Alternate Path] " + fileOnly);

                    if (!ProcessFile(searchPath, manifestItem, ref strECID))
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static bool ProcessFile(string filename, BuildManifestItem manifestItem, ref string strECID)
    {
        manifestItem.Found = true;

        System.IO.BinaryReader binaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename));
        binaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(-2125, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End);
        byte[] magic = binaryReader.ReadBytes(4);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        foreach (byte b in magic)
        {
            sb.Append((char)b);
        }
        string magicstr = sb.ToString();
        if (magicstr != "DICE")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  - ERROR: Magic string not found! (DICE)");
            return false;
        }

        // chew bytes to get to the ecid
        binaryReader.ReadBytes(8);

        // get the ECID
        byte[] ecid = binaryReader.ReadBytes(8);
        StringBuilder sbECID = new StringBuilder(20);
        for (int idxECID = ecid.Length - 1; idxECID >= 0; idxECID--)
        {
            sbECID.Append(ecid[idxECID].ToString("x2"));
        }

        string strThisECID = sbECID.ToString();
        if (strECID != null && strThisECID != strECID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  - ERROR: ECID Mismatch (Had: " + strECID + " Found: " + strThisECID + ")");
            return false;
        }
        else if (strECID == null)
        {
            strECID = strThisECID;
            Console.WriteLine("Detected ECID: " + strECID);
        }

        binaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(-2125, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End);

        byte[] signedBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(2125);
        string signedBytesEncoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);

        StringBuilder formattedBlobDataBuilder = new StringBuilder(3000);
        for (int idxChar = 0, colCount = 0; idxChar < signedBytesEncoded.Length; idxChar++, colCount++)
        {
            formattedBlobDataBuilder.Append(signedBytesEncoded[idxChar]);
            if (colCount + 1 == 60)
            {
                formattedBlobDataBuilder.Append("\n\t\t");
                colCount = -1;
            }
        }
        string formattedBlobData = formattedBlobDataBuilder.ToString();
        manifestItem.BlobData = formattedBlobData;

        return true;
    }
}

public class BuildManifestItem
{
    string _key;

    public string Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; }
    }
    string _path;

    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set { _path = value; }
    }
    string _partialDigest;

    public string PartialDigest
    {
        get { return _partialDigest; }
        set { _partialDigest = value; }
    }

    string _blobData;

    public string BlobData
    {
        get { return _blobData; }
        set { _blobData = value; }
    }

    bool _found;

    public bool Found
    {
        get { return _found; }
        set { _found = value; }
    }
}

public class BuildManifestReader
{
    private Dictionary<string, BuildManifestItem> _manifestItems;

    public Dictionary<string, BuildManifestItem> ManifestItems
    {
        get { return _manifestItems; }
        set { _manifestItems = value; }
    }

    public BuildManifestReader(string manifestFilename)
    {
        _manifestItems = new Dictionary<string, BuildManifestItem>();
        System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Util.ReadEmbeddedResource(manifestFilename));
        string elementName = null;
        bool foundManifest = false;
        BuildManifestItem manifestItem = null;
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                elementName = xmlReader.Name;
            }
            else if (elementName == "key" && xmlReader.Depth == 5 && xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                if (xmlReader.Value == "ApBoardID")
                {
                    foundManifest = false;
                }
                else if (xmlReader.Value == "Manifest")
                {
                    foundManifest = true;
                }
            }
            else if (elementName == "key" && xmlReader.Depth == 6 && xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                if (foundManifest)
                {
                    manifestItem = new BuildManifestItem();
                    manifestItem.Key = xmlReader.Value;
                }
            }
            else if (elementName == "key" && xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text && xmlReader.Value == "Path")
            {
                string path = GetPath(xmlReader);
                manifestItem.Path = path;
            }
            else if (elementName == "key" && xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text && xmlReader.Value == "PartialDigest")
            {
                string digest = GetPartialDigest(xmlReader);
                digest = digest.Replace("\n", "");
                digest = digest.Replace("\t", "");
                manifestItem.PartialDigest = digest;

                if (!_manifestItems.ContainsKey(manifestItem.Key + "-" + manifestItem.Path))
                {
                    _manifestItems.Add(manifestItem.Key + "-" + manifestItem.Path, manifestItem);
                }
                manifestItem = null;
            }
        }
    }

    string GetPath(System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        string elementName = null;
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
                continue;

            if (xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                elementName = xmlReader.Name;
            }
            else if (elementName == "string" && xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                return xmlReader.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    string GetPartialDigest(System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        string elementName = null;
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
                continue;

            if (xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                elementName = xmlReader.Name;
            }
            else if (elementName == "data" && xmlReader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                return xmlReader.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Util
{
    public static System.IO.Stream ReadEmbeddedResource(string resourceName)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly curAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string [] resources = curAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (string resource in resources)
        {
            if (resource.EndsWith(resourceName))
            {
                return curAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}
Diagnostic: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enab
le DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and
 pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderI
mpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at SHSH_Tool.BuildManifestReader..ctor(String manifestFilename) in C:\Users\A
dministrator\Desktop\shsh\Program.cs:line 323
   at SHSH_Tool.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sh
sh\Program.cs:line 87
Complete.

Comment: Can't you reduce this to a small example?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783189/xml-reader-wants-prohibitdtd-to-be-false-but-it-is

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you gave us the actual XML document that you are reading.  It probably has a "DOCTYPE" at the top which specifies a .DTD file.

Either edit the document to not have the DOCTYPE, or programatically ignore the DOCTYPE.  Here is how you can do that: [Ignore DOCTYPE .dtd, but .dtd file must still exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894317/ignore-doctype-dtd-but-dtd-file-must-still-exist/3908542#3908542)